# c# - pop up new window

Tags: c#

I would like to make application which submits articles to article directories (Just to speed up my own work. not commercial). I can submit forms, save captcha to computer and now I would like to display it in new window - so that I can enter them from my desktop.

I know only basic things about c#, never coded any visual code myself - always use in made functions.

So any help how can I make this happen ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try visual studio express edition for windows development

http://www.microsoft.com/express/windowsdevelopment/